# cycle renderer with multiple textures on single mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a mesh body, an avatar,  with a  skin texture and a shirt texture on top of the shirt.  Using blender renderer it works perfectly, Using cycles it does not.  the skin texture is fed into one input of a mix shader, the other input gets the shirt texture with one link to the color input and the other to the alpha input.
When I hi-light image texture input with the skin the shirt dissapears completely,  when I hi-light the shirt input the shirt appears and the skin turns black.
Here is a link to the blend file 
 http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50999﻿

The "standard" answer says plug one texture into one input of mix shader, the other texture,the shirt into the other and the alpha of the  shirt into the alpha input on the mix shader.  Does not work :(

I've seen this question posted before and the answers don't work for me.

Following is screen capture showing shaders and render viewport.
[image: screen capture showing render in viewport and shaders]

I'm using Blender v2.79.6 from 2019-01-14.
Halp :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get multiple textures on a single material. In the image I show a skin texture overlaid with a shirt texture. The shirt has transparent component allowing one to see the skin below.[image: The image shows blender 2.80 shaders view with skin and shirt textures added]

Comment: Hello Vince, please provide more explanation on how you solved the problem

Comment: the image should explain it.  In the  original I was feeding the mix shader directly into the material output.  In the image above you see I added a diffuse shader.  I just tried the above layout with blender 2.79.7 and it still acts strangely.  If setup as above when I left click on the skin input text shader, the shirt disapears and all I see is skin.  If I click on the text input ( starlight_upper.png in above ) then the shirt ( see above for image of the shirt ) appears and the skin turns black. in 2.79 I've tried both the mix shader and the color mix shader.  Same results. That help?

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few problems here, you should probably watch some basic cycles material tutorials. You appear to have misread some stuff about alpha blending, it is not how you would achieve what you are trying to do.

The way to do this would be to assign one material to the shirt (using the shirt texture) and a whole **different material** to the skin. As they are separate meshes this should be fairly easily.

Another problem I have noticed is that you are plugging colour data (the yellow node connections) into shader data (the green ones). While cycles will try and make sense of this, generally if you are plugging connections between different coloured sockets, then something isn't quite right. In this case you want the put a shader node (Like a diffuse BSDF) in between the texture and the mix shader or output(if you get rid of the mix shader).

Comment: The mesh is from a product to support SecondLife(SL) and does not support cycles. I'm trying to figure out how to migrate to cycles eg. Blender 3.80 with minimal impact.  The shirt and skin are supplied as textures only.   Normally one would be able to add undershirt, shirt, jacket etc as another texture layer.  Important when one uses this model for creating a new undershirt,shirt,jacket.   There is a jpg template for making one's own undershirt,shirt,jacket that is applied as a texture only in SL. So seperate material would not work at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the upper body is all a single material, and the shirt and skin are both textures that are added.  Blender 2.79b and 2.97.7 still don't work, while 2.80 does.